# MySQL em aplicações Java Desktop para vários estabelecimentos

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, aplicação-desktop

Olá, se eu fizer uma aplicação Java Desktop com banco de dados MySQL, que será entregue para vários estabelecimentos utilizarem, como fica o banco de dados? Tem alguma sugestão? A aplicação, eu consigo fazer com que seja instalada facilmente, mas e a parte de banco de dados? Cada local vai ter que instalar o MySQL e também criar as tabelas necessárias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende o que você quer. Se cada estabelecimento deve ter o seu banco de dados independente, então, o banco de dados é instalado em um servidor físico dentro do estabelecimento e os terminais se conectam a ele por meio de um IP do tipo *192.168.X.X*. Outra possibilidade é que cada estabelecimento escolha hospedar em algum lugar externo (tal como algum servidor de computação em nuvem), mas daí necessita de conexão com a internet e não apenas de uma rede local.

Se você quiser que todos eles usem o mesmo banco de dados MySQL, você é que o hospeda em algum lugar (possivelmente em algum serviço de computação em nuvem) e então todos se conectam a ele por meio do IP público ou *hostname* que você diponibilizar.

De qualquer forma, tudo isso se resume à string de conexão: `jdbc:mysql://<host-do-servidor>:3306/<nome-do-seu-database>`. No lugar do `<host-do-servidor>` você põe o IP do servidor ou o hostname do mesmo. Você pode deixar o IP ou hostname fixo no código-fonte ou pode lê-lo de um arquivo de configuração.

Quanto a criação das tabelas, você as criaria como parte do processo de instalação do MySQL. Se for instalar um MySQL em cada estabelecimento, então nessa ocasião é que você criaria as tabelas. Se for fazer um único local onde todos acessem, você só precisaria criar as tabelas uma única vez.

No mais, você também deve ficar de olho na segurança. Se você tiver vários locais diferentes mandando instruções do tipo `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` e `SELECT` para um único lugar centralizado, é muito fácil para alguém dar um jeito de enviar instruções como essas por fora do seu programa. Basta ter o username, a senha e a string de conexão que podem ser recuperadas de dentro do programa facilmente. É por causa disso que muitas vezes se utiliza aplicações *server-side* que acesssam o banco de dados de forma exclusiva e os aplicativos clientes só devem se comunicar por meio da aplicação no servidor: Isso garante o encapsulamento do banco de dados.